# How to manually return a custom Dart Object with two different keys from a Future call and use the data in FutureBuilder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get information from two different keys of the response of an API call. Looks like that in the Future call I can return only the response of one key. To explain more, the code below shows the what I am trying to achieve:

```
Future<PlayerInfo> fetchContestants() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(URL));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    String data = response.body;
    
    var playerData = jsonDecode(data)['players'];
    var player = playerData.firstWhere(
        (element) => element['id'] == 'a8e69669-b4bb-5cb3-9bec-7d860fc080b1');
    print(player);

    var clubData = jsonDecode(data)['clubs'];
    var club =
        clubData.firstWhere((element) => element['id'] == player['club_id']);

    print(clubData);

    return PlayerInfo.fromJson(player);
  }
```

So, I am successfully getting the data that I want, as I can see from the print methods, but I want to return both playerData and clubData at the same return method so I can use this information later on FutureBuilder widget. I was trying to mutate an object like in Javascript, but with Flutter and Dart it gets a bit more complicated according to me, because I need to define the tyepes and because I wanted to do this manually, not using any json serializer package as I am trying to learn the basics of Dart and Flutter. Any way that I could make soemthing like this work?

Here is the PlayerInfo model:

````
class PlayerInfo {
  final String name;
  final String surname;
  final String id;
  final String clubId;
  final String position;
  final int jerseyNumber;
  final String image;
  final int totalScore;
  final int avgScore;

  PlayerInfo(
      {required this.name,
      required this.surname,
      required this.id,
      required this.clubId,
      required this.position,
      required this.jerseyNumber,
      required this.image,
      required this.totalScore,
      required this.avgScore});

  factory PlayerInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PlayerInfo(
      name: json['first_name'],
      surname: json['last_name'],
      id: json['id'],
      clubId: json['club_id'],
      position: json['position'],
      jerseyNumber: json['jersey_number'],
      image: json['avatar_urls']['large'],
      totalScore: json['total_score'],
      avgScore: json['avg_score'],
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Why can't you return both pieces of data in an object?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz what do you mean? How can I return both pieces of data in an object and then later create a `factory PlayerInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` from the JSON I am returning on the Future? Is that even possible?

Comment: I am printing this according to your answer: `print({'player': player, 'club': club});` which correctly prints what I want, but when I `return PlayerInfo.fromJson({"player": player, "club": club});` I cannot access the values in the Builder.

Comment: @klevisx would you please include the `PlayerInfo` model in the question itself?

Comment: @lepsch I was trying to also create a Model for Club as like ClubInfo but then I would have had conflicting returns.